# Load Default selected ajax value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an form where the values are loaded from database using Ajax. But I want One default value instead of "SELECT COUNTRY OPTION". I Tried many things but nothing is worked. I want to set USA As Default Country

Here is My Js and PHP File.
https://file.io/Gu17TeX8lKRs

[image: Form Image]

Main Js Code.

```
function cdp_load_countries(modal) {

    $("#country" + modal).select2({
        ajax: {
            url: "ajax/select2_countries.php",
            dataType: 'json',

            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: params.term // search term
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: data
                };
            },
            cache: true
        },
        placeholder: translate_search_country,
        allowClear: true
    }).on('change', function (e) {

        var country = $("#country" + modal).val();

        $("#state" + modal).attr("disabled", true);
        $("#state" + modal).val(null);

        if (country != null) {
            $("#state" + modal).attr("disabled", false);
        }

        cdp_load_states(modal);
    });
}
```

And Php File

```
<?php
require_once("../loader.php");
$db = new Conexion; 
$sWhere = '';
if (isset($_REQUEST['q'])) {
    $search = cdp_sanitize($_REQUEST['q']);
    $sWhere = "and  name LIKE '%" . $search . "%'";
}
$list = array();
$data = [];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM cdb_countries where is_active=1 $sWhere";
$db->cdp_query($sql);
$db->cdp_execute();

$datas = $db->cdp_registros();

foreach ($datas as $key) {

    $data[] = array('id' => $key->id, 'text' => $key->name);
}

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Comment: I Added Main Part of code.

Comment: So set the entry for `USA` in the data that you are returning _as_ selected, as explained here, https://select2.org/data-sources/formats#selected-and-disabled-options ...? And if you then want to also automatically populate the dependent(?) `Status` field (which should really be labeled `State` instead, right?) with the US states, trigger a `change` event in the select2, after you populated it.